# Phonegap AdMob does not work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova, admob, phonegap

My problem is that admob plugin is not working on the PhoneGap IOS testing app (this is the plugin: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova)

var isAppForeground = true;

```
function initAds() {
  if (!admob) {
    var adPublisherIds = {
      ios : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"
      },
      android : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
      }
    };

    var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;

    admob.setOptions({
      publisherId:      admobid.banner,
      interstitialAdId: admobid.interstitial,
      //tappxIdiOS:       "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-iOS-IIII",
      //tappxIdAndroid:   "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-Android-AAAA",
      //tappxShare:       0.5,

    });

    registerAdEvents();


  } else {
    alert('admobAds plugin not ready');
  }
}

function onAdLoaded(e) {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      console.log("An interstitial has been loaded and autoshown. If you want to load the interstitial first and show it later, set 'autoShowInterstitial: false' in admob.setOptions() and call 'admob.showInterstitialAd();' here");
    } else if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE_BANNER) {
      console.log("New banner received");
    }
  }
}

function onPause() {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    admob.destroyBannerView();
    isAppForeground = false;
  }
}

function onResume() {
  if (!isAppForeground) {
    setTimeout(admob.createBannerView, 1);
    setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
    isAppForeground = true;
  }
}

// optional, in case respond to events
function registerAdEvents() {
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdFailedToLoad, function (e) {});
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdOpened, function (e) {});
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, function (e) {});
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLeftApplication, function (e) {});
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onInAppPurchaseRequested, function (e) {});

  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}
```

The plugin is successfully installed and I placed these 3 lines under onDeviceReady:

```
initAds();
admob.createBannerView();
admob.requestInterstitialAd();
```

Everything after the lines above, in the same function (onDeviceReady) is not executed (the function crashes).

Again, I use the PhoneGap app for testing (from AppStore).

Comment: I think that plugin not working anymore. Try this [one](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free), its simple for use and there are not too much issues

Comment: I have found the problem. It looks like the plugin which I have mentioned is not working with the PhoneGap live app testing from the AppStore. The plugin works only after I build the app and install it on the phone like a normal app.